# Type deduction in C++14 if you don't have the source

Tags: c++14, return-type-deduction

With the new return type deduction in C++14, you can write code like:

```
auto almostPi (void) { return 3.14159; }
```

and the function itself will use the return value to decide the *actual* return type for the function, in this case a `double`.

How is this done for things like a general purpose library where you don't *have* the source code, instead only having a header file containing something like:

```
auto almostPi (void);
```

How does the compiler in that case know to warn you if you do:

```
char *dodgyPointer = almostPi();
```

from your own code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call the function if its return type can't be deduced:

```
$ cat test.cpp
auto almostPi(void);

void test() {
  char *dodgyPointer = almostPi();
}

$ g++ -c test.cpp --std=c++14
test.cpp: In function ‘void test()’:
test.cpp:4:24: error: use of ‘auto almostPi()’ before deduction of ‘auto’
   char *dodgyPointer = almostPi();
                        ^
```

The library would just have to declare the actual return type in its header.